# XOR certain bytes in c

Tags: c, cryptography, xor

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am new to c and only learning. So this questain may seem confused. I have an unsigned int value that I need to split into bytes then xor certain bytes together and then get the result. I want represent the value as (0, a0 ⊕ a1,a2 ⊕a3,0).

Decimal value = 62910759 or Hex value = 3BFF127;

```
unsigned int value = 62910759;
```

// W  = (0, a0 ⊕ a1,a2 ⊕a3,0);

```
unsigned int L = 0x04000000L^ W ;
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to XOR?

Comment: I want to convert the value into bytes so I can xor certain bytes. Sorry if my terms are incorrect.

Comment: You mean someting like this: `(x & 0xff) ^ ((x >> 8) & 0xff)) ^ ((x >> 16) & 0xff) ^ ((x >> 24) & 0xff)` ?

Comment: So you want to XOR each byte in the value, i.e. `03 XOR BF XOR F1 XOR 27`?

Comment: Yes dbush sorry for confusion

Comment: Note: `L` means the constant `0x04000000L` is at least long/unsigned long`.  `unsigned int L` is an `unsigned`.  If code is assigning a constant that is at least `long/unsigned long`, better to assign it to a `long/unsigned long` rather than an `unsigned`.  `unsigned long L = 0x04000000L^ W ;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but i calculate the bytes first and then XOR some of them:

```
unsigned int value = 62910759;
unsigned char a = value >> 24 & 0xFF; // First byte/ high byte
unsigned char b = value >> 16 & 0xFF;
unsigned char c = value >> 8 & 0xFF;
unsigned char d = value & 0xFF; // Last byte/ smallest byte
printf("%.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X\n", a,b,c,d);

unsigned char aXORb = a^b; // a XOR b
unsigned char bXORc = b^c;
unsigned char cXORd = c^d;
unsigned char dXORa = d^a;

printf("%.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X\n", aXORb,bXORc,cXORd,dXORa);
```

[Try it here.](http://ideone.com/qiLj3D)

Output:

```
03 BF F1 27
BC 4E D6 24
```

Note: I think uint8_t would be more "C-like" but the result will be the same anyway.

@Jimbo Jones Here is the last step. The zeros are unnecessary, but i included them for better understanding the code.

```
unsigned int result = (0x00 << 24) + (aXORb << 16) + (cXORd << 8) + 0x00;
Method(0x02000000L^ result);
```

If you mean with W = (0, a0 ⊕ a1,a2 ⊕a3,0) that the first 8 bit are 0 and the next 8 a XOR b and so on.

Comment: How would I complete this step  Method(0x02000000L^ W) where W  = (0, a0 ⊕ a1,a2 ⊕a3,0) and Method accepts an unsigned int

Comment: Using bitwise operators on a signed int is not a good idea, because it can lead to poorly-specified behavior bugs in many cases. Using bitwise operators on character types is therefore not a good idea either, because they will end up as signed int through implicit integer promotion. Thus this whole code is vulnerable to bugs.

Comment: @Lundin corrected to unsigned int. Would uint8_t instead of unsigned char make it better?

Comment: If type `uint8_t` exist, it is the same size/range of `unsigned char`.  In that case, use whatever type that best conveys the meaning.  `unsigned char` is more portable as `uint8_t` is common, yet an optional type.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for all your help, your a legend

Comment: @izlin Both types have the same problem with implicit integer promotion.

Comment: @chux `uint8_t` is more portable since it is of deterministic size. It doesn't matter that stdint.h is optional in C11, because nobody in the real world is going to accept a compiler which does not support stdint.h. Such crap compilers should not be used, so designing for portability to them, if they even exist, is nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin  `uint8_t` is not more nor less portable than `unsigned char` given `uint8_t` exist as you suggest that only that case is considered.  When `uint8_t` exist, it is the same size/range as `unsigned char` and does not make code more/less portable.  Perhaps you can present a use case where when `uint8_t`  exist and using one or the other improves _portability_?  As I see it, when `uint8_t` exist, the selection is for code clarity and not portability.

Comment: @chux  The obvious: `type t; for(uint8_t* ptr=(uint8_t*)&t; ptr < &t; ptr++) bits += 8;` This code is portable with uint8_t but could break with unsigned char, because unsigned char is not guaranteed to have 8 bits. (Strict aliasing is not a concern here unless the compiler is hopelessly broken.)

Comment: @Lundin Disagree with "could break" sample code.  For `uint8_t` to exist, `unsigned char`  must also be 8 bit.  If `unsigned char` is > 8 bit, `uint8_t` does not exist and code sample would not compile due to `uint8_t`, not `unsigned char`.   "number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field" is `CHAR_BIT` which is `unsigned char` bit size.  Both `unsigned char` and `uint8_t` cannot have padding.

Comment: @chux That only proves the point. If `char` is 16 bit on the given system, and you have written a program which relies on a byte being 8 bits, then `uint8_t` will not compile, while `unsigned char` will silently compile and give the wrong result.

Comment: `type t; for(uint8_t* ptr=(uint8_t*)&t; ptr < &t; ptr++) bits += 8;` // ensured to be safe by the compiler

Comment: `type t; for(unsigned char* ptr=(unsigned char*)&t; ptr < &t; ptr++) bits += 8;` // dangerous and non-portable

Comment: @Lundin `type t; for(unsigned char* ptr=(unsigned char*)&t; ptr < &t; ptr++) bits += CHAR_BIT;` is portable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130225/discussion-between-chux-and-lundin).